# ASP.NET Users not publishing to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2012

I've got a simple MVC 4 application with a user and role defined in the ASP.NET Configuration.  They work fine locally (Running with F5) but when published to Azure Web Site the users don't exist or at least, when trying to log in I can't.  Could either be the user doesn't exist or that the passwords isn't matching.

e.g.  I have a page for Admins only, I have one admin user.  Locally I created the user and role in the ASP.NET Configuration page and I can log in as Admin and access the secured page.  After publishing to Azure Web Site I can't log in as Admin.

Can anyone help?  How do I publish my ASP.NET Configuration?

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web

Comment: The problem maybe because of locally you use localdb or sql server, and you need to publish your db or exec sql script on sql azure db to setup data with users and roles.

Comment: Thanks @sound, any advise on how to do that?  Is there anything actually wrong with using the ASP.NET configuration to manage roles when you're publishing to Azure?

Comment: @sound How could I manage my roles that way?  I create roles locally, is there a way to to it in Azure?

Answer (score 1):

As @Sound pointed out, you are probably missing the users from the DB that is hosted on Azure.  You can access Sql Azure using Sql Management Studio once you open up the firewall through the Azure portal.  From there, you can run a script to insert the users, or do it manually through SSMS.

There are many options for migrating data, the above just being a few.  You might also look into EF Data Migrations as that might be a good fit as well.

Comment: Thanks, I've used EF to generate the database for the site content.  How do I use that for the users and roles though?

Comment: As I know ASP.NET Configuration applies settings to DB your project is currently connected(localdb or SQL Server). Try to change connection string to sql azure db and then run configuration tool again.

Comment: You can create "Database Initializers" that will create some default data along with your database